AWS crawler creating Null values for partion columns
I am having some country level partitioned data in s3 and crawler is crawling the this root folder and creating a table. No Null value is there for country code. But when looked in the Athena, there are null values for the country code.
Upon looking at the data in s3, there are some history files which are placed at the root level but not in country(partioned) column.
Will this having data cause issue in Athena table
What is the root cause for the null country codes
How to remove these nulls
-Table
--country=ind
---some files
--country=usa
---some files
--hist file1
--hist file2


ALTER TABLE abc 
DROP PARTITION (country = SELECT country FROM abc WHERE country NOT IN ('ind', 'usa'));

